# Which Models to prefer

Tags: regression, self-study, generalized-linear-model, interpretation, econometrics

(Model1)
    . reg lnQ lnL lnK COOP

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         lnQ |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         lnL |   .7682515   .0662688    11.59   0.000     .6364455    .9000576
         lnK |   .0537095   .0495861     1.08   0.282    -.0449153    .1523342
        COOP |   -.158698   .0660776    -2.40   0.019    -.2901238   -.0272723
       _cons |   4.946906   .2614977    18.92   0.000     4.426797    5.467014
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(model 2)
    . reg lnQ lnL lnK COOP COOP_LNL

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         lnQ |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         lnL |   .7339817   .0719376    10.20   0.000      .590875    .8770885
         lnK |   .0536394   .0494509     1.08   0.281    -.0447341     .152013
        COOP |   -.690055   .4454689    -1.55   0.125    -1.576235    .1961245
    COOP_LNL |   .0888071   .0736333     1.21   0.231    -.0576729    .2352872
       _cons |   5.147985   .3095237    16.63   0.000     4.532244    5.763726

    firm            float   %9.0g                 firm code (or firm ID)
    va              float   %9.0g                 value added in millions of lire
    labor           float   %9.0g                 permanent employees at year end
    capital         float   %9.0g                 fixed assets at historical cost in millions of lire
COOP = a dummy variable for a worker cooperative. Conventional firms have code (or ID) numbers (given by FIRM) less than 100, while the code (or ID) numbers for worker cooperatives exceed 99.
COOP_LNL=COOP*lnL
    lnQ = the natural logarithm of output (value added)
lnL = the natural logarithm of labor
lnK = the natural logarithm of capital
```

How to determine which models to prefer? My thinking is do a F-test on COOP and COOP_LNL to see if this p-value is bigger than the p-value of COOP for model 1. If this is the case, I will pick model 1 because it has less p-value...Is it the right way to approach it? Is there any better way or different way?

Comment: What are COOP? lnQ? lnL? lnK? Could you give us a bit more context?

Comment: In addition to contextual judgements you should consider the Akaike and Bayesian Information Criteria (AIC/BIC) which are very frequently used in such situations.

Comment: @Memming: I just revised it to give more context to the questions

Answer (score 1):

I agree that BIC and AIC are good indicators.

Not knowing too much about the data, I would prefer Model 1. Model 2 sets off to test the interaction between COOP and lnL. And apparently such interaction is not significant (p = 0.231) and the adjustment to the slope of lnL is only 0.089, which is quite small compared to the slope of 0.734 for those with COOP = 0. I would proceed to remove the interaction term and choose the first model.

Of course, p-value isn't everything. If you have started to test such interaction then you should report both. And I'll also plot the group-based regression lines (lnQ vs. lnL, one line for COOP = 0 and one for COOP = 1) and examine the actual slopes difference. If you feel they are very different and deserved to be modeled as such, then it's your choice. But nonetheless, I'd attempt to report both in such scenario. Because once the reviewers see an interaction term with p > 0.05, they may question you what would the model look like if you had removed the interaction.